# How to make a NSWindow like this one from Tweetbot?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'd like to make a `NSWindow` like this one. How can i do it?
Sorry if this is an noobie question but i'm figuring it out.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the title bar like this:

```
[myWindow setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```

I'm not sure what capabilities that Tweetbot window has, but if you want to move the window around by dragging the white area, you can use a custom NSView and override `mouseDownCanMoveWindow` to return `YES`.

Comment: thanks, but it's working nice but the corners of the window are very pointy. how can i make round ones like the image?

Comment: Check out [this sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html).